# ToolboxItem attribute in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to prevent a public class deriving from the Control class to be displayed in the Toolbox of Visual Studio? Is there the equivalent of the ToolboxItem attribute in Silverlight. If yes, in what namespace can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

using **[DesignTimeVisible(false)]** attribute which is available in **System.ComponentModel** namespace